# AuthUserSession OnAuthenticated method fires?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I'm really confused about when the method OnAuthenticated() from AuthUserSession fires??
It fires from a Login of for example ASP MVC LOGINPAGE or from where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you successfully [authenticate with ServiceStack Authentication service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) that by default is hosted at `/auth` once you register ServiceStack's the **AuthFeature** plugin.

It is completely independent from MVC, ASP.NET or any other WebFramework you might he hosting ServiceStack with.

Comment: right, so If I want to fire that method by using some login page from asp mvc .it is possible? @mythz

Comment: @rr7 See the [AccountController.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/CustomAuthenticationMvc/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L48-L58) in the [CustomAuthenticationMvc](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/CustomAuthenticationMvc/) ServiceStack.UseCases example. There are a [number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12064166/85785) of [different](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18384632/85785) examples on StackOverflow as well.